# xsd file content xml is not loading in chrome browser

Tags: c#, .net

I have an XSD file in my project and I want to write the content of this XSD file using filestream but it throws error eg:
**ReadTimeout = 'fs.ReadTimeout' threw an exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException'
WriteTimeout = 'fs.WriteTimeout' threw an exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException'**

**Content of XSD file**

```
       <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
       <xs:schema id="Resources" 
       targetNamespace="http://tempuri.org/SecurityZoneResources.xsd" 
       elementFormDefault="qualified" xmlns="http://tempuri.org/Resources.xsd" 
       xmlns:mstns="http://tempuri.org/Resources.xsd" 
       xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:msdata="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xml-msdata">
       <xs:element name="Document">
       <xs:complexType>
        <xs:choice minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded">
            <xs:element name="Details">
                <xs:complexType>
                    <xs:sequence>
                        <xs:element name="ID" type="xs:long" />
                        <xs:element name="DomainID" type="xs:long" />
                        <xs:element name="GroupID" type="xs:long" minOccurs="0" />
                        <xs:element name="Name" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" />
                        <xs:element name="Owner" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" />
                        <xs:element name="Description" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" />
                        <xs:element name="Policy" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" />
                        <xs:element name="IsDeleted" type="xs:boolean" />
                        <xs:element name="Created" type="xs:dateTime" />
                        <xs:element name="CreatedBy" type="xs:string" />
                        <xs:element name="Updated" type="xs:dateTime" minOccurs="0" />
                        <xs:element name="UpdatedBy" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" />
                        
                    </xs:sequence>
                </xs:complexType>
            </xs:element>
            
        </xs:choice>
    </xs:complexType>
    <xs:unique name="DocumentKey1">
        <xs:selector xpath=".//mstns:Details" />
        <xs:field xpath="mstns:ID" />
    </xs:unique>
    <xs:unique name="Table1_Constraint1">
        <xs:selector xpath=".//mstns:SecurityZoneResources" />
        <xs:field xpath="mstns:ResourceID" />
    </xs:unique>
</xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```

**FileStream**

```
private FileStream getFileStream(string fileName)
{
    // read Schema
    FileStream fs = new FileStream(String.Format(@"{0}\{1}", Server.MapPath(@"..\Schemas"), fileName),
        FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);

    return fs;
}
```

This fs throws error
**ReadTimeout = 'fs.ReadTimeout' threw an exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException'
WriteTimeout = 'fs.WriteTimeout' threw an exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException'**

How to solve it? Anybody have any clue? Why am I getting ReadTimeout and WriteTimeout error.

Comment: Where exactly is the error going to happen? Because this only returns the stream. Could you please post the part of your code thats reading the data actually in?